# Replacement for Gallery-Widget to enable Horizontal scrolling

Tags: android, android-gallery, horizontal-scrolling

Is there an alternative to the deprecated gallery-widget that has the same/similar abilities?

I would like to have a single "row" of images + title-textviews where the user can scroll through horizontally. I tried to do that with a GridView, but it only offers vertical scrolling, but not herizontal scrolling. I also don't want to use a lot of image/textviews because of bad performance.

So, is there a solution for this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like android.widget.HorizontalScrollView is what you want:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/HorizontalScrollView.html